# For function on jQuery lookup by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the offset top of the second element matching my selector.

```
var barBlocks = $('.bar-block');
console.log(barBlocks[1]);
console.log(barBlocks[1].offset().top);
```

Outputs

```
<div class="bar-block"><span style="width:30.8%;" class="bar"></span><span>30.8%</span></div>
Uncaught TypeError: barBlocks[1].offset is not a function
```

Not sure how to get the offset method to run on the results of the lookup by class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery object instead of directly accessing by index, which gives you the DOM element itself, for which the method `offset` is not defined.

```js
var barBlocks = $('.bar-block');
console.log(barBlocks.eq(1).offset().top);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-block"><span style="width:30.8%;" class="bar"></span><span>30.8%</span></div>
<div class="bar-block"><span style="width:30.8%;" class="bar"></span><span>30.8%</span></div>
```

Comment: @PeterBreen No problem.

Comment: I asked a follow up here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395885/text-counter-animation-bug-jquery, if you want to knock out another one :)