# Text Counter Animation Bug jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a text animation, counting up from 0.  My devsite is [http://35.209.165.103/~reprotech/](http://35.209.165.103/%7Ereprotech/). (it's the second animation down, under "Our Storage") that I'm having some trouble with.  The animation is almost running perfectly, but runs into problems when the user refreshes the page while already over the elements, it can get stuck at 0.  Any advice on how to remedy?

Here's the jQuery which makes the animation

```js
var barBlocks = $('.bar-block');
barBlocksTriggered = [false, false, false];
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (barBlocksTriggered[i] == false) {
      var CT = barBlocks.eq(i).offset().top,
        CH = 0,
        WH = $(window).height(),
        WS = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (WS > (CT + CH - WH)) {
        var el = barBlocks.eq(i);
        var barCount = el.find('.bar-count');
        barCount.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: barCount.text()
        }, {
          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            barCount.text(now.toFixed(1));
          }
        });
        barBlocksTriggered[i] = true;
        console.log(i + " triggered");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.our-storage{

    width:100%;
}
 .average-wrap{
    padding:45px
}
 .average-wrap h5,.average-wrap p{
    margin-bottom:33px
}
 .average-wrap h5{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:800;
    text-transform:uppercase
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:300px">Scroll down</div>
<div class="our-storage equal-height" style="height: 1054px;">
  <h2>Our Storage</h2>
  <div class="average-wraps">
    <div class="average-wrap">
      <h5>Bla 1</h5>
      <p>Text text</p>
      <div class="bar-block"><span style="width:56.2%;" class="bar"></span><span><span class="bar-count">0.0</span>%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="average-wrap">
      <h5>Bla 2</h5>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div class="bar-block"><span style="width:30.8%;" class="bar"></span><span><span class="bar-count">0.0</span>%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="average-wrap">
      <h5>Bla 3</h5>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div class="bar-block"><span style="width:13%;" class="bar"></span><span><span class="bar-count">13.0</span>%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including any relevant HTML.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and other stuff

Comment: @mpdlugjan Thank you, it's not quite the same behavior as on the site, but it's similar in that the animation function gets triggered but the animation doesn't happen.

Comment: With this code snippet I can't repuduce it. The posted link gets into a 404 error. Do you mean, if the user is on top page again, the counter is still showing?

Comment: In the code snippet, I only see the bottom one working correctly, which is a different problem than the live page, but seems related.  On the live page, the problem comes when a user scrolls to the content and then reloads while viewing that content (an unlikely case).  I'm not sure how to reproduce that with a snippet.

I'm not sure why that link isn't working for you, works fine for me...

@Reporter